# Change CSS that's attached to the HTML tag depending on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a Homepage that uses Scrollmagic.js to scroll up and down the page and that requires the HTML tag to be relatively untouched. On every other page I need the HTML tag to have a height of 100% or the sticky footer CSS won't work but if I add 100% height to the homepage, then no scrolling. So is there a way in either CSS or jQuery that can change HTML height depending on which page the user is on?

or is there a sticky footer method out there that doesn't use a height of 100% on the HTLM tag like:

```
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: I don't know how dirty it is, but create another css file, that has just that one style block. include that css file to all those pages where needed. be sure to prioritize the new file (add it after the regular one). If needed, use `!important`.

Comment: Hmm, that's just made me think, as it's a Jekyll site I could use a grubby little inline style for the post pages, thanks.

Comment: or that, yes. although inline is a bit messier. What if you have to change a little something later on. then you have to change all the pages separately. it's better to have all the pages link to one source.

Comment: sigh, true : ] oh well I give Jeff's solution another go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the URL to check which page you are on, and adjust the CSS according to the page.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var pageurl = url.substring(url.indexOf('.com')+4,url.length);
    var html = document.querySelector('html');

    if(pageurl !== "/index.html") {
      /* adjust css if we're not on the index.html page */
      html.style.height = "100%";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like what I'm after but I get a "Uncaught TypeError: url.indexof is not a function"?

Comment: @Nsokyi It's my fault, I did a mistake and forgot a capital O in `indexOf`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats awesome!

Comment: I think the OP needs `height` not `width` but otherwise this looks solid.

Comment: @apokryfos Wow you're right. How did I miss that? Fixed.